# How to make a socket.io connection between two different interfaces?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm actually trying to make a real-time connection between two different apps. I've found a bunch of tutorials about how to make a chat using socket.io, but that doesn't really help me since it's just the same app duplicated in multiple windows.

I'm making a pick & ban overlay for League of Legends in local development. My first thought was to display the empty overlay on one hand and create an interface to manually update it on the other hand. Socket.io seems to be the right thing to use in my case since it can provide new data without having to reload the component.

This is what I wrote in both apps :

```
const express = require('express');
const socket = require('socket.io');

// App setup
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(4200, function () {
    console.log('Listening to requests on port 4200')
});

// Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Socket setup
const io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Made socket connection', socket.id);

    socket.on('change', function (data) {
        io.sockets.emit('change', data);
    });
});
```

But I fail to connect them as they have to listen to the same port. What am I doing wrong?
(Forgive my bad English and lack of syntax, I'm doing my best here. :p)

Answer (score 1):

I am certainly not an expert on network programming, but as far as I know you need to have one listening app (backend) and another one to connect to it (client). And you define what happens with all the data (messages) that backend recieves (for example sending the messages it recieves to all the clients in the same chat room).

If I am correct to assume you are trying to connect two listening apps?

simple google search of "nodejs socket server client example" revealed this https://www.dev2qa.com/node-js-tcp-socket-client-server-example/ might wanna take your research in this direction

Answer (score 1):

u can try something like this way

```
var express = require('express');
var socket  = require('socket.io');

// App setup
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(8080, () => {
   console.log('App started')
})

// Static file
app.use(express.static('public'))

// Socket SetUp
var io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('made the connection')

    socket.on('chat',data => {
       io.sockets.emit('chat',data)
    });

    socket.on('typing',data => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing',data);
    });
})
```

create another file and

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080')

// Elenment
var message  = document.getElementById('message');
    handle   = document.getElementById('handle');
    btn      = document.getElementById('send');
    output   = document.getElementById('output');
    feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');
// Emit Events

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   socket.emit('chat', {
      message: message.value,
      handle: handle.value
   })
})

message.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
   socket.emit('typing', handle.value)    
})

socket.on('chat',data => {
   feedback.innerHTML = '';
   output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle +': </strong>' + 
  data.message + '</p>'
 })

socket.on('typing', data => {
  feedback.innerHTML = '<p><emp>' + data + ' is typing a message... </emp></p>'
})
```

details are given here [node socket chat app](https://github.com/sayalok/chatApp-using-node-express-and-socket)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out. Here's how it works using express and vue together :

First, setup socket.io in your express server js file :

```
const express = require('express')
const { Server } = require('socket.io')
const http = require('http')

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'REMOVE']
    }
})
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New socket user')

    socket.on('SEND_MESSAGE', data => {
        console.log('received message in back')
        io.emit('MESSAGE', data)
    })
})


server.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server started on port : ${PORT}`)})
```

As you can see we received from the client "SEND_MESSAGE" and we trigger MESSAGE from the server to forward the information to all the clients. The point I was missing is that we bind SEND_MESSAGE on the socked created from the connection but we emit from the io server.

Now you vue part :

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      messages: [],
      inputMessage: null,
      socket: io('http://localhost:8080')
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.socket.on('MESSAGE', data => {
      this.messages.push(data)
    })
  },

  methods: {
    sendMessage() {
      const message = {
        senderID: this.myID,
        message: this.inputMessage,
        sendAt: new Date()
      }

      this.socket.emit('SEND_MESSAGE', message)
      this.inputMessage = null
    },
  },
}
```